# Why does the UI flicker when using navigation component(xml) with Fragment and ComposeView?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Jetpack Compose in an existing app with a XML based navigation graph.

The transition from FragmentA to FragmentWithComposeView ( and vice-versa) is not smooth and causes the UI to flicker. The UI is janky even with a single Text component.
The transition uses a global action with below for the enter,exit, popEnter and popExit parameters.

```
@anim/nav_default_enter_anim.xml
@anim/nav_default_exit_anim.xml
```

Using below library versions:

```
activity compose - 1.4.0
compose material - 1.0.5
compose tooling - 1.0.5
material compose theme adapter - 1.1.3
```

Is there a solution or is XML based UI better in this case?

Comment: Same here... First time it doesn't work properly, then yes. Did you solved it?